# How can I formally describe how $\lim \frac{p}{q}$ where p and q are polynomials behaves?

Tags: calculus, limits

As a part of one of my assignments I was given a task to somewhat formally describe the relationship of two polynomials $p, q$, and their limit

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}$$

I do understand the principle behind this, that the polynomial with a higher degree will *outgrow* the other one for a sufficiently large $n$. I also understand that if I have something like $x^2+3x+4$, and $n \rightarrow \infty$, then I can just think of this as $x^2$ (since the quadratic term grows much faster.)

The problem is that I don't know how to formally describe this. Neither the definition of a limit, nor the rules for limit arithmetic seem to apply here.

**edit:** Thanks for the prompt answers, though I probably didn't describe my question clearly. My issue is that I need to describe/show/prove that the limit is what it is (for example $\frac{a}{b}$ for polynomials of equal degree). I need to describe **why the limit is behaving this way for polynomials.**

Answer (score 3):

Try writing the polynomials this way:

$\displaystyle \frac {p(x)}{q(x)} = \frac {a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_nx^n}{b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + \ldots + b_mx^m}$

$=\dfrac{x^n(a_n + \ldots + a_1 x^{1-n} + a_0x^{-n})}{x^m(b_m + \ldots  + b_1 x^{1-m} + b_0x^{-m})}$

Then it should be easier to explain the limiting behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ and $q$ two polynomials with leading coefficients $a_s x^s$ and $b_t x^t$ respectively so

- if $s>t$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}=\operatorname{sign}\left(\frac{a_s}{b_t}\right)\infty$$
- if $s=t$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}=\frac{a_s}{b_t}$$
- if $s<t$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}=0$$